# No thumbnails on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, images, external-hdd, veracrypt

I have a VeraCrypt volume mounted from an external hard drive and the thumbnails for >90% of the files don't seem to load. Only the first few load then the rest show a clock icon. When I open the file, however, everything is fine. I recently reinstalled Linux Mint.

Here is what the directory looks like when I open it:

[image: Directory]

Also the files (png, jpg, mov, mp4) are not extremely large. Many are less than 2MB. When I open the directory, the CPU and memory usage is very low.

Any ideas? I have already tried changing the setting that limits the size a file must be to have a thumbnail generated. No results.

Comment: @Goro I have tried that as suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/a/213636. No success though.

Answer (score 3):

Occasionally the thumbnailer gets stuck for me (see https://github.com/linuxmint/xplayer/issues/157, its probably xplayer being obsolete, sounds like in the future this will be fixed)

to "unstuck" the thubnailer, I find it from a terminal with `pgrep -af thumb`, for me Nemo is using '/usr/bin/xplayer-video-thumbnailer', so I can "unstuck" the worker queue by killing this process `killall /usr/bin/xplayer-video-thumbnailer` which will abort creating whichever thumbnail is stuck

Comment: Very nice, it was stuck for me also! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case it might be the package `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin` missing. 
First you can check if it's installed with:

```
dpkg -s libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
```

If not installed, then you can just install it:

```
sudo apt install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in that directory go to edit -> preferences. A popup screen should open. Go to the previewtab. Set Show Thumbnails to "Always".

Does that fixes the problem?

Comment: I've tried this before and it hasn't worked.